# A behavior of mapUnderscoreToCamelCase in MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

**BACKGROUND**

I have a following setting in my `mybatis-config.xml` like below.

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
          <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
    </settings>
.
.
.
```

As you already know, and like the setting name says, it enables an automatic mapping for changing underscore column names to camelcase names.

**SO, DECLARING RESULTMAP LIKE BELOW BECOMES A REDUNDANT JOB.**

```
<resultMap id="userModel" type="UserModel">
    <result property="userCode"     column="USER_CODE"      />
    <result property="userId"       column="USER_ID"        />
    <result property="userName"     column="USER_NAME"      />
    <result property="password"     column="USER_PASSWORD"  />
    <result property="land"         column="LAND"           />
</resultMap>
.
.
.
```

---

**PROBLEM**

I thought at first that this could make any column names camel-cases. But *it does not, it seems.*

Simply take a look at these two examples.

```
<select id="select" resultType="hashMap">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT  ID
                ,USER_ID
                ,USER_NAME
                ,REG_DATE
                ,UPD_DATE

        FROM   TEST
    ]]>
</select>
```

Above one is not converted to camelcase.

```
<select id="selectTutorial" resultType="UserModel">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT  ID
                ,USER_ID
                ,USER_NAME
                ,REG_DATE
                ,UPD_DATE

        FROM   TEST
    ]]>
</select>
```

**But this one is converted to camelcase very nicely.**

The only difference is their `resulyType`. One is `hashMap` and another is `UserModel`.

---

This situation makes me think that a model is a must for the column mapping. So I took a shot with a wild guess like below.

```
public class UserModel {
    int id;
    String userId;
    String userName;
    Date regDate;
    Date updDate;
    .
    .
    .


// Change its variable names to...  
public class UserModel {
    int ID;
    String userID;
    String userNAME;
    Date REGdate;
    Date UPDdate;
    .
    .
    .
```

And that was right. Mybatis follows the model's member names. So my questions narrow down to this one.

1. Can I get the camelcase key names even when the mapper's `resultType` is `hashMap`?

Answer (score 0):

I usually change SQL like: `SELECT ID id, USER_ID userId, USER_NAME userName ...` which is really not a big deal but gives more predictable results then a potential solution you trying to figure out.

When binding to POJOs `mapUnderscoreToCamelCase` option could still be useful so I can use queries like `SELECT * FROM ...` if possible.